# Could not find method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor

Tags: java, android-studio

This is just a basic Q&A app.
I get the error when I tried to press a `radiobutton` on the app interface.
Here is my main class:

```
public class Balance extends AppCompatActivity {

private int score = 0; //answer score
private int PreviousScore;
private int i = 0;
private Vibrator myVib;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance);

    final TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); //button

    myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    question(); //call params for question

    //button listener, when button clicked, produce output on textfield "Score"
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myVib.vibrate(70);
            PreviousScore = score;

            //Score.setText(String.valueOf(action()));
            //Score.setText(score);
            i++;
            question();

            RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            mRadioGroup.clearCheck();

        }

    });




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_balance, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void question(){
//basically assigning strings to radiobuttons here
}


private void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    myVib.vibrate(50);

    // Check which radio button was clicked

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.AnswerA:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 0;
            break;
        case R.id.AnswerB:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.AnswerC:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 2;
            break;
    }
}

private String action(){

    String action = null;
    if (score <= 16)
        action= "Low Risk";
    else if(score > 16 & score <= 32)
        action = "Medium Risk";
    else if(score > 32 & score <= 48)
        action = "High Risk";
    else if(score > 48 & score <= 64)
        action = "Very High Risk";

    return action;
}


}
```

Here is my content view

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/Score"
    android:text="score goes here"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerA"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerB"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerA"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerC"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerB"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerD"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerC"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Text"
    android:id="@+id/Next_Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/currentscore"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Next_Text"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Logcat:

```
 02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.user.tinetti, PID: 9082
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton with id 'AnswerB'
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:310)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:269)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-20 14:14:46.484 9082-9082/com.example.user.tinetti E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I see the same problem. Will update this if I figure out a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set attribute OnClick for all RadioButtons.Android is triggering an event may be when you are clicking on radio button.It is unable to find onClick method.It may be in recent version(API 23).It is my practical answer
 **android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"** add this to your radio button for both.
Define a **onRadioButtonClicked** method in your activity which is linked to your layout.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. In my situation, I needed to remove android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" for the Radio Buttons to work. In place of defining an onRadioButtonClicked as you suggest, I defined the click listener on the RadioGroup instead with setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `private void onRadioButtonClicked` to `public void onRadioButtonClicked`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but didn't want to use the button on click for each button.  Based on @ray-li suggestion this is what I did.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pirates"
        />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ninja"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

and the listener:

```
val multiChoice : RadioGroup = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_choice_dialog, null) as RadioGroup
multiChoice.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checkedId: Int) {
        val checked = when (checkedId) {
            R.id.radio_ninjas -> "radio_ninjas"
            R.id.radio_pirates -> "radio_pirates"
            else -> "unknown: 0x%08x".format(checkedId)
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener: checked = $checked")
    }
})
```

Steve S.

Comment: You did not assign an id to your radio group i.e. multi_choice_dialog but in kotlin code you are referring it.

Comment: Actually, I never use the id for the group.  Since I created the group and you use the id to find it, I don't need one.